# converting a list of times to total time

Tags: python, list, function, time

I have 3 lists, one for hours, one for minutes, and one for seconds. What I have done is create a function that will take 3 lists as input and calculate the total amount of time.

My issue is that the function is so redundant and my question to you, is simpy: what is a better way to do this.

Here is my function:

```
def final_time(hours,minutes,seconds):
    draft_hours = sum(hours)
    draft_minutes = sum(minutes)
    draft_seconds = sum(seconds)
    adding_seconds = str(draft_seconds/60.0)
    second_converting = adding_seconds.split(".")
    seconds_to_minutes = int(second_converting[0])
    seconds_to_seconds = draft_seconds - (seconds_to_minutes * 60)
    total_seconds = str(seconds_to_seconds)
    more_minutes = draft_minutes + seconds_to_minutes
    adding_minutes = str(more_minutes/60.0)
    minute_converting = adding_minutes.split(".")
    minutes_to_hours = int(minute_converting[0])
    minutes_to_minutes = more_minutes - (minutes_to_hours * 60)
    total_minutes = str(minutes_to_minutes)
    total_hours = str(draft_hours + minutes_to_hours)
    return total_hours + " hours, " + total_minutes + " minutes, and " + total_seconds + " seconds."
```

here is an example:

```
my_hours = [5, 17, 4, 8]
my_minutes = [40, 51, 5, 24]
my_seconds = [55, 31, 20, 33]
print final_time(my_hours,my_minutes,my_seconds)
```

above returns:

```
36 hours, 2 minutes, and 19 seconds.
```

so it does work, but as you can see, the function is just not a pythonic nor efficient function...**what would a better method be?**

Comment: Questions that begin, "*so it does work*" are better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s = sum(hours)*3600+sum(minutes)*60+sum(seconds)
return '%d hours %d minutes %d seconds'%( s/3600, (s%3600)/60, s%60)
```

Comment: I like your conversion to seconds more than mine.  Mine assumes that there are the same number of elements in `hours`,`minutes` and `seconds`, but I suppose I don't see any reason why that has to be the case in general.  (+1)

Answer (score 4):

I would probably convert it all to seconds first:

```
seconds = sum(3600*h + 60*m + s for (h,m,s) in zip(hours,minutes,seconds)
```

Now break it back down:

```
n_hours,minutes = divmod(seconds,3600)
n_minutes,n_seconds = divmod(minutes,60)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def HMSToSeconds(H,M,S):
   return H*3600 + M * 60 + S

def SecondsToHMS(seconds):
   hours,seconds = divmod(seconds,3600)
   mins,seconds = divmod(seconds,60)
   return hours,mins,seconds

def final_time(hours,minutes,seconds):
    draft_hours = sum(hours)
    draft_minutes = sum(minutes)
    draft_seconds = sum(seconds)
    total_seconds = HMSToSeconds(draft_hours,draft_minutes,draft_seconds)
    return SecondsToHMS(total_seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use time objects from Datetime http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects

That would be something like :

```
def final_time(hours,minutes,seconds):
    times=[datetime.time(hours[i],minutes[i],seconds[i]) for i in range(0,length(hours))]
    return sum(times)
```